# Why is my peak execution memory in spark 0?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Data file (CSV) description:

- On disk 12.1GiB
- Memory Serialized - 1.9 GiB

I run the following code:

```
###imports
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as w
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

##start session without off-heap
spark = SparkSession.builder.\
config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled",False).\
config("spark.executor.cores","2").\
config("spark.executor.instances","1").\
config("spark.executor.memory","500m").\
config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", False).\
config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes","13g").\
getOrCreate()


####read in a 1.9 GiB Serialized CSV
df_covid = spark.read.csv("gs://xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/spark_datasets/covid13g.csv",
                          header=True, inferSchema=False)
df_covid.cache()

######check the number of partitions
df_covid.rdd.getNumPartitions() #output 2

###To ensure filters don't get pushed down
df_covid = df_covid.withColumn("_catted", F.concat_ws('',*df_covid.columns))

######Apply filter
df_covid = df_covid.filter(F.length(df_covid._catted) > 20)

######count post filter rows
df_covid.count()
```

The job completes successfully and the following is the snapshot of my executor tab from spark web UI

[image]

I do not understand 2 things about this:

1. Why is the peak execution memory 0? I am reading all the data, concatenating all the columns and also applying filters to the data. The filters are not pushed down at the read itself since the the filter is on the concatenated column
2. Why is the peak JVM memory off-heap not 0? I have not configured off-heap memory and it is off by default then why am I seeing off-heap JVM memories in the tab?

Answer (score 0):

For your Q1, if you dive into the Spark [memory management overview](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview):

> Memory usage in Spark largely falls under one of two categories: execution and storage. Execution memory refers to that used for computation in shuffles, joins, sorts and aggregations, while storage memory refers to that used for caching and propagating internal data across the cluster.

Not all action will use execution memory in Spark. It's typically used for short-lived objects and computation like data shuffling. Therefore, even you use concatenating and filtering, no execution memory will be used.

Comment: While concat and filter, the data has to be held in some memory and the output data also has to be generated that passes to count. Which memory is used to hold these datasets then?

Comment: @figs_and_nuts When you call `count()`, `cache()` will be executed and your data (`df_covid` - only read from gs) persists in the memory (look at the quote that I mentioned above). Therefore the storage memory will be used. However, when you call `concat()` and `filter()`, you didn't do any caching or persisting afterwards. Therefore, no memory is used to save the transformed data and the counting output is passed back to driver directly.

Comment: Actually, the data I'm using is quite large and is entirely persisted on the disk. How can concat happen without the data being in RAM? Where exactly in RAM is it?

Comment: I hope my question is clear. My point is that since the concat and filter are taking place they can only take place on the data that is in RAM. Where exactly in RAM is my data if not in execution memory? You can see from the image ive attached in question that it aint in the storage memory either

Comment: Also, I can remove the line doing ```cache``` and the code still works and there is still no execution memory.